# Error(38,1): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem with some `Oracle SQL` code I'm running and I can't for the life of me see what the problem is. I have this code that works:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE        XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD (pSC_VER_ID IN NUMBER)
AS

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD
--
-- DESCRIPTION:
-- Called when SC wkflw is marked complete.
--
-- CALLED BY:
-- Scorecard workflow
--
-- MODIFICATION HISTORY:
-- 2008-06-24 CJW   Setup.
-- 2008-08-22 CJW   Change to pull from views.
-- 2009-02-09 CJW   Enhancements.
-- 2010-08-18 EC    BVD update. 'STD_INDS_CODE' changed to SIC_COD9 code
-- 2013-01-17 EC    Version 7 updates. Remvoed logging to another table as cuases problems for Smartest to Support and investigate error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

vCP_ID              NUMBER;
vErrCode               NUMBER(38);
vErrMsg               VARCHAR2(250);
vPROCNAME              VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

vPROCNAME := 'XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD';


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Copy data to OBX_CRM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
select CP_ID  INTO vCP_ID from sc_version sv inner join scorecard sc on sc.id = sv.scorecard_id 
and sv.id = pSC_VER_ID;

INSERT INTO OBX_CRM_V2 
(
    OBX_CRM_ID,
    CPTY_KEY,
    CPTY_NAME,
    DB_NUMBER,
    SIC_CODE,
    CPTY_SCORE,
    APPROVED_LIMIT,
    SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    LIMIT_EXPIRATION,
    LIMIT_COMMENT,
    APPROVAL_0,APPROVAL_0_DT,
    APPROVAL_1,APPROVAL_1_DT,
    APPROVAL_2,APPROVAL_2_DT,
    APPROVAL_3,APPROVAL_3_DT,
    APPROVAL_4,APPROVAL_4_DT,
    APPROVAL_5,APPROVAL_5_DT,
    APPROVAL_6,APPROVAL_6_DT,
    APPROVAL_7,APPROVAL_7_DT,
    CRDT_INS,
    CRDT_INS_LIMIT,
    CRDT_INS_COVERAGE,
    CRDT_INS_EXPIRY,
    CPTY_COMMENT,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_TS
)    
SELECT
    NULL                                                                                                                        AS OBX_CRM_ID,
    TO_CHAR(CP.COUNTERPARTY_NUMBER)                                                                                                      AS CPTY_KEY,
    TO_CHAR(CP.NAME)                                                                                                                     AS CPTY_NAME,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)  FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10079)                AS DB_NUMBER,
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(D.ELEMENT_VALUE)) FROM DNB_COMPANY_DETAIL D WHERE D.COMP_ID =  CP.ID
        AND D.ELEMENT_CODE = 'SIC_COD9')                                                                                    AS SIC_CODE,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(SCORE)            FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE  S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )                   AS CPTY_SCORE,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10071)               AS APPROVED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUGG_CRED_LIM)  FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )               AS SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10086)               AS LIMIT_EXPIRATION,  
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRT_APC') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS LIMIT_COMMENT,                   
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10077)               AS APPROVAL_0,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10088)               AS APPROVAL_0_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10130)               AS APPROVAL_1,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10131)               AS APPROVAL_1_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10072)               AS APPROVAL_2,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10085)               AS APPROVAL_2_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10070)               AS APPROVAL_3,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10083)               AS APPROVAL_3_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10075)               AS APPROVAL_4,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10082)               AS APPROVAL_4_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10078)               AS APPROVAL_5,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10081)               AS APPROVAL_5_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10073)               AS APPROVAL_6,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10080)               AS APPROVAL_6_DT, 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10128)               AS APPROVAL_7,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10127)               AS APPROVAL_7_DT,  
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS CRDT_INS,                   
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_AMT') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_LIMIT, 
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_COV') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_COVERAGE, 
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_VAL') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_EXPIRY, 
    TO_CHAR(CP.COMMENTS)                                                                                                                 AS CPTY_COMMENT,    
    TO_CHAR(vPROCNAME)                                                                                                                   AS CREATED_BY,
    SYSDATE                                                                                                                     AS CREATED_TS
FROM

    COUNTERPARTY        CP   
WHERE
     CP.ID = vCP_ID
;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this code that doesn't:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE        XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD (pSC_VER_ID IN NUMBER)
AS

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD
--
-- DESCRIPTION:
-- Called when SC wkflw is marked complete.
--
-- CALLED BY:
-- Scorecard workflow
--
-- MODIFICATION HISTORY:
-- 2008-06-24 CJW   Setup.
-- 2008-08-22 CJW   Change to pull from views.
-- 2009-02-09 CJW   Enhancements.
-- 2010-08-18 EC    BVD update. 'STD_INDS_CODE' changed to SIC_COD9 code
-- 2013-01-17 EC    Version 7 updates. Remvoed logging to another table as cuases problems for Smartest to Support and investigate error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

vCP_ID              NUMBER;
vErrCode               NUMBER(38);
vErrMsg               VARCHAR2(250);
vPROCNAME              VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

vPROCNAME := 'XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD';


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Copy data to OBX_CRM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
select CP_ID  INTO vCP_ID from sc_version sv inner join scorecard sc on sc.id = sv.scorecard_id 
and sv.id = pSC_VER_ID;

INSERT INTO OBX_CRM_V2 
(
    OBX_CRM_ID,
    CPTY_KEY,
    CPTY_NAME,
    DB_NUMBER,
    SIC_CODE,
    CPTY_SCORE,
    APPROVED_LIMIT,
    SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    LIMIT_EXPIRATION,
    LIMIT_COMMENT,
    APPROVAL_0,APPROVAL_0_DT,
    APPROVAL_1,APPROVAL_1_DT,
    APPROVAL_2,APPROVAL_2_DT,
    APPROVAL_3,APPROVAL_3_DT,
    APPROVAL_4,APPROVAL_4_DT,
    APPROVAL_5,APPROVAL_5_DT,
    APPROVAL_6,APPROVAL_6_DT,
    APPROVAL_7,APPROVAL_7_DT,
    CRDT_INS,
    CRDT_INS_LIMIT,
    CRDT_INS_COVERAGE,
    CRDT_INS_EXPIRY,
    CPTY_COMMENT,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_TS,
    S_RAIVA,
    S_RCSDA,
    S_RCEDA,
    S_ARPT,
    S_ARPM,
    S_GAEVA
)    
SELECT
    NULL                                                                                                                        AS OBX_CRM_ID,
    TO_CHAR(CP.COUNTERPARTY_NUMBER)                                                                                                      AS CPTY_KEY,
    TO_CHAR(CP.NAME)                                                                                                                     AS CPTY_NAME,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)  FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10079)                AS DB_NUMBER,
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(D.ELEMENT_VALUE)) FROM DNB_COMPANY_DETAIL D WHERE D.COMP_ID =  CP.ID
        AND D.ELEMENT_CODE = 'SIC_COD9')                                                                                    AS SIC_CODE,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(SCORE)            FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE  S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )                   AS CPTY_SCORE,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10071)               AS APPROVED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUGG_CRED_LIM)  FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )               AS SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10086)               AS LIMIT_EXPIRATION,  
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRT_APC') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS LIMIT_COMMENT,                   
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10077)               AS APPROVAL_0,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10088)               AS APPROVAL_0_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10130)               AS APPROVAL_1,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10131)               AS APPROVAL_1_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10072)               AS APPROVAL_2,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10085)               AS APPROVAL_2_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10070)               AS APPROVAL_3,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10083)               AS APPROVAL_3_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10075)               AS APPROVAL_4,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10082)               AS APPROVAL_4_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10078)               AS APPROVAL_5,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10081)               AS APPROVAL_5_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10073)               AS APPROVAL_6,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10080)               AS APPROVAL_6_DT, 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10128)               AS APPROVAL_7,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10127)               AS APPROVAL_7_DT,  
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS CRDT_INS,                   
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_AMT') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_LIMIT, 
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_COV') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_COVERAGE, 
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_VAL') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_EXPIRY, 
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10285)         AS S_RAIVA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10286)         AS S_RCSDA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10287)         AS S_RCEDA,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10288)         AS S_ARPT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10289)         AS S_ARPM,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10290)         AS S_GAEVA,
    TO_CHAR(CP.COMMENTS)                                                                                                                 AS CPTY_COMMENT,    
    TO_CHAR(vPROCNAME)                                                                                                                   AS CREATED_BY,
    SYSDATE                                                                                                                     AS CREATED_TS
FROM

    COUNTERPARTY        CP   
WHERE
     CP.ID = vCP_ID
;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The difference between the two is the addition of:

```
S_RAIVA,
S_RCSDA,
S_RCEDA,
S_ARPT,
S_ARPM,
S_GAEVA
```

Near the top, and the below near the bottom.

```
(SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10285)         AS S_RAIVA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10286)         AS S_RCSDA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10287)         AS S_RCEDA,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10288)         AS S_ARPT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10289)         AS S_ARPM,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10290)         AS S_GAEVA,
```

I get the error:

> `Error(38,1): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`

when I try to compile it but I don't understand why. Line 38 is just: 
`INSERT INTO OBX_CRM_V2` and doesn't give me any explanation of where the problem exists, and the extra lines conform to the same syntax as the code that works, as far as I can see. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm a complete novice at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You insert to the `OBX_CRM_V2` table data returned by the `SELECT`. Trouble is the order of columns do not match. Your new columns are specified at the end of `INSERT`, but are not at the very end of the main `SELECT`.

What happens here, the new `SELECT` statements near the end of the code will try to insert to `CPTY_COMMENT, CREATED_BY, CREATED_TS, S_RAIVA, S_RCSDA, S_RCEDA` and not to `S_RAIVA, S_RCSDA, S_RCEDA, S_ARPT, S_ARPM, S_GAEVA`, which is what you need.

Should work after reordering:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE        XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD (pSC_VER_ID IN NUMBER)
AS

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD
--
-- DESCRIPTION:
-- Called when SC wkflw is marked complete.
--
-- CALLED BY:
-- Scorecard workflow
--
-- MODIFICATION HISTORY:
-- 2008-06-24 CJW   Setup.
-- 2008-08-22 CJW   Change to pull from views.
-- 2009-02-09 CJW   Enhancements.
-- 2010-08-18 EC    BVD update. 'STD_INDS_CODE' changed to SIC_COD9 code
-- 2013-01-17 EC    Version 7 updates. Remvoed logging to another table as cuases problems for Smartest to Support and investigate error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

vCP_ID              NUMBER;
vErrCode               NUMBER(38);
vErrMsg               VARCHAR2(250);
vPROCNAME              VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

vPROCNAME := 'XP_CLOSE_SCORECARD';


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Copy data to OBX_CRM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
select CP_ID  INTO vCP_ID from sc_version sv inner join scorecard sc on sc.id = sv.scorecard_id 
and sv.id = pSC_VER_ID;

INSERT INTO OBX_CRM_V2 
(
    OBX_CRM_ID,
    CPTY_KEY,
    CPTY_NAME,
    DB_NUMBER,
    SIC_CODE,
    CPTY_SCORE,
    APPROVED_LIMIT,
    SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    LIMIT_EXPIRATION,
    LIMIT_COMMENT,
    APPROVAL_0,APPROVAL_0_DT,
    APPROVAL_1,APPROVAL_1_DT,
    APPROVAL_2,APPROVAL_2_DT,
    APPROVAL_3,APPROVAL_3_DT,
    APPROVAL_4,APPROVAL_4_DT,
    APPROVAL_5,APPROVAL_5_DT,
    APPROVAL_6,APPROVAL_6_DT,
    APPROVAL_7,APPROVAL_7_DT,
    CRDT_INS,
    CRDT_INS_LIMIT,
    CRDT_INS_COVERAGE,
    CRDT_INS_EXPIRY,
    CPTY_COMMENT,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_TS,
    S_RAIVA,
    S_RCSDA,
    S_RCEDA,
    S_ARPT,
    S_ARPM,
    S_GAEVA
)    
SELECT
    NULL                                                                                                                        AS OBX_CRM_ID,
    TO_CHAR(CP.COUNTERPARTY_NUMBER)                                                                                                      AS CPTY_KEY,
    TO_CHAR(CP.NAME)                                                                                                                     AS CPTY_NAME,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)  FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10079)                AS DB_NUMBER,
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(D.ELEMENT_VALUE)) FROM DNB_COMPANY_DETAIL D WHERE D.COMP_ID =  CP.ID
        AND D.ELEMENT_CODE = 'SIC_COD9')                                                                                    AS SIC_CODE,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(SCORE)            FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE  S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )                   AS CPTY_SCORE,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10071)               AS APPROVED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUGG_CRED_LIM)  FROM SC_VERSION S WHERE S.ID = pSC_VER_ID )               AS SUGGESTED_LIMIT,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10086)               AS LIMIT_EXPIRATION,  
     (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRT_APC') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS LIMIT_COMMENT,                   
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10077)               AS APPROVAL_0,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10088)               AS APPROVAL_0_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10130)               AS APPROVAL_1,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10131)               AS APPROVAL_1_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10072)               AS APPROVAL_2,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10085)               AS APPROVAL_2_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10070)               AS APPROVAL_3,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10083)               AS APPROVAL_3_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10075)               AS APPROVAL_4,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10082)               AS APPROVAL_4_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10078)               AS APPROVAL_5,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10081)               AS APPROVAL_5_DT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10073)               AS APPROVAL_6,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10080)               AS APPROVAL_6_DT, 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10128)               AS APPROVAL_7,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10127)               AS APPROVAL_7_DT,  
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)     FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                       AS CRDT_INS,                   
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_AMT') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_LIMIT, 
    (SELECT CASE
          WHEN value_float IS NULL
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(value_string, ',',''))
          ELSE TO_NUMBER(value_float)
       END      FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_COV') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_COVERAGE, 
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)       FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE V 
        WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE A WHERE NAME = 'S_CRDT_INS_VAL') AND OWNER_ID = CP.ID)                   AS CRDT_INS_EXPIRY, 
    TO_CHAR(CP.COMMENTS)                                                                                                        AS CPTY_COMMENT,    
    TO_CHAR(vPROCNAME)                                                                                                          AS CREATED_BY,
    SYSDATE                                                                                                                     AS CREATED_TS,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10285)         AS S_RAIVA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10286)         AS S_RCSDA,
    (SELECT TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE)     FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10287)         AS S_RCEDA,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10288)         AS S_ARPT,
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE_STRING)   FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10289)         AS S_ARPM,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10290)         AS S_GAEVA
FROM

    COUNTERPARTY        CP   
WHERE
     CP.ID = vCP_ID
;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you Apo, that worked. I have rearranged the order columns and it now compiles without error. I hadn't realised the order made any difference and figured it should be smart enough to realise the line tagged with 'As (column name)' at the end should be for that column. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Check the table description for `OBX_CRM_V2`. You're attempting to insert  number into date column.

Either `S_RAIVA` or `S_GAEVA` in your `INSERT` -- both `NUMBERs` is actually, trying to insert a value into `DATE` column actually.

```
 (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10285)         AS S_RAIVA,
```

Or

```
 (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VALUE_NUMBER) FROM SC_ELEMENT S WHERE S.SC_VERSION_ID = pSC_VER_ID AND S.DATA_ELEMENT_ID = 10290)         AS S_GAEVA,
```

A simple example for this.

```
insert into employee(empno,hiredate) values (1,100);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So, make sure, the order of values in `INSERT` is matching the order of column in table.